# MYSQL: How to check if a string contains a value within the same row

Tags: mysql

I would like to check if a string in a certain cell of the database is part of a string in another cell of the same row.

The following example makes it more clear. Let's say that my table looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------------+
|  Name   |     Couple      |
+---------+-----------------+
| Mark    | Mark & Thomas   |
| Chris   | Thomas & Logan  |
| Patrick | Logan & Patrick |
| Thomas  | Chris & Mark    |
| Logan   | Patrick & Chris |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Then the result of my query would have to be this:

```
+---------+-----------------+
|  Name   |     Couple      |
+---------+-----------------+
| Mark    | Mark & Thomas   |
| Patrick | Logan & Patrick |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Because Mark and Patrick are part of the string in the Couple field.

I gave it a try, but I don't think it's the right way to do this:

```
Select * from table where Couple like %Name%
```

Thanks for your answer(s)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax was close, you can use:

```
Select name, couple
from yt 
where Couple like concat('%', Name, '%');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04cf9f/3)

Answer (score 4):

Think you have the columns the wrong way round, and you need the wild cards in the string you are comparing.

Maybe:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Couple LIKE CONCAT('%', Name, '%')
```